# How to place menu icon on top-left corner using React Active?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to make the usual drawer navigator app by having the Menu icon/button at the top-left corner of the screen, I can get it to the header/top but can't get it to the left, it always get stuck in the middle somehow, here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the render code:

```
render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Icon name='ios-menu' onPress={() =>
                            this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} />
                    </Left>
                </Header>
                <AppTabNavigator/>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

I've tried setting some stylesheet properties to alignSelf, anything to center it but could not manage to get it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have empty Body and Right components inside the Header

Comment: You are right! Just the "Right" element was enough, body not necessary.